# In C appending elements to an array like it happens in Python

Tags: arrays, c, append

In my game/program..
I am editing my obj_list, item_list etc. like item_list[0] = hp_potion..
Instead of this,
I really want to do this: item_list.append(rect).
So I can get rid of writing every single index and remembering them to add another variable.

If there is a solution. I am happy to know that. Thanks for your time.

I tried for loops etc. Nothing works like python syntax.

Comment: In C, you have to manage arrays and lists manually. Fixed-length arrays cannot be extended. You need to use dynamic memory allocation routines, like `malloc`, `realloc`, and `free`, and you must manage the lengths yourself. You can write your own routine to do the append operation, but you will have to learn enough C to write it.

Comment: Hi! C is a completely different beast to Python. Try using c++ first because it has built in std::array, std::list and other containers :)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks I will try to use malloc. So there is no way appending such way for a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C does not provide a built-in function to add an element to an array. Arrays in C are fixed length. But Python lists can grow dynamically. If you want to implement Python **list** like structure in C, you can use **linked list** with dynamic memory allocation.